# CapsLock breaks Eterm keybinds

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, xterm

In my Ubuntu Server 14 with FluxBox i use to bind actions on Eterm.
This is my `user.cfg` file:

```
[...]

begin actions
    bind ctrl shift button3 to string '^[]6;14^G'
    bind ctrl button3 to menu "Eterm"
    bind ctrl button2 to string '^[[?30t'
    bind ctrl button1 to string '^[]5;^G'
    # mine actions start here
    bind End to echo '^E'
    bind F1 to echo '^[OP'
    bind F2 to echo '^[OQ'
    bind F3 to echo '^[OR'
    bind F4 to echo '^[OS'
    bind F5 to echo '^[5'
    bind F6 to echo '^[6'
    bind F10 to echo '99^Msigi^M'
end actions

[...]
```

as you can see I bind the `End` and the `F` buttons to some specific command.
I need this commands on a telnet sessions.
This work well, but if I activate the `Caps Lock` none of previous actions work (even the Eterm native actions).

I can't figure out why this happen, someone can?

---

## A Solution

A solution that works for me, as sudgested by `@Thomas Dickey`, is to use the modifier `Lock`, So, this action:

```
begin actions
    [...]
    bind End to echo '^E'
    [...]
end actions
```

become this

```
begin actions
    [...]
    bind End to echo '^E'
    bind Lock End to echo '^E'
    [...]
end actions
```

And now the `End` button works well even with the CapsLock active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CapsLock* is (almost) the same as holding down the shift-key.

Eterm (actually rxvt, since that's where Eterm started) treats the shift- and control-modifiers for function (and cursor) keys as different values.

Here are pointers to a few tables to illustrate:

- *[Rxvt Technical Reference](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/rxvt/html/rxvtRef.html)* (see table near the end)
- ***[rxvt](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_R_X_V_T)*** in ncurses terminal database
- ***[Eterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_E_T_E_R_M)*** in ncurses terminal database
- *[Table of function-keys for XTerm and other Terminal
  Emulators](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm-function-keys.html)* (a digression from the [XTerm FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html))
- *[Terminal Function Key Escape Codes](http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/term-function-keys.html)* (some of the commentary on the page is inaccurate).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eterm. Is that actually what's going on? I would have thought that it reacted to the Lock modifier (which is not the same thing as holding down Shift!).

Comment: I have CapsLock on the left, and NumLock on the numeric keypad.  They have different functions (and the latter is a modifier in X).  I said "almost" because CapsLock is basically for the alphabet (most of the main keyboard), while shift applies everywhere.  When I tested with OP's problem on *my* machine, it applied to the function-keys.  ymmv.

Comment: Caps Lock is also a modifier (`Lock`). I've had trouble with software that considered `Lock+key` and `key` to be different bindings and didn't have an interface to supply bindings for `Lock+key` (including some versions of fvwm, IIRC).

Comment: Molte grazie! Non sapevo che `Lock` è un modificatore ... E 'abbastanza per me di utilizzare che nelle mie" azioni ".

Comment: Ups... looks like somethig went wrong here... I meant: "Thanks a lot! I didn't know that `Lock` is a modifier. This is enough for me, and solve my problem with this."